En mi BBDD MySQL tengo un campo de tipo "time", como puedo insertar un formato 40:00:00 (h:m:s)?
Si en mi BBDD MySQL tengo un campo que es de tipo "time", luego a la hora de mapearlo (utilizando ORM de Doctrine y Symfony 7.0) tengo lo siguiente:
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'estimated_hours', type: Types::TIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $estimatedHours = null;

Si desde el frontend envio 40 y este quiero insertarlo en la BBDD como 40:00:00...
¿Como podría hacerlo? ¿Es posible?
Pd: Si hago por ejemplo
$estimatedHours = $taskData->estimated_hours;
$timeIntervalEst = new DateInterval('PT' . $estimatedHours . 'H');

A la salida me da 1d y 16:00:00h y esto ultimo es lo que me inserta en la BDD los 16h, pero no consigo sacar y introducir el formato que yo quiero (en este caso 40:00:00).
Gracias de antemano!

Puedes intentar utilizar  SEC_TO_TIME(), solo toma en cuenta que esta función toma la cantidad de segundos y te retorna tiempo, en tu caso podrías intentar SEC_TO_TIME($estimatedHours*60*60) y tendrás 40:00:00. Suerte

pero no consigo sacar y introducir el formato que yo quiero. Ese es tu error, porque los formatos no son algo que debas guardar. Debes guardar el dato limpio de formato y formatear en el contexto. Imagina que necesitas representar el mismo dato en diferentes formatos, según determinadas circunstancias. Tomas el dato y formateas en la salida. Si te pones a guardar formatos no sólo te expones a un rompecabezas, sino que expones los datos a ser guardados con errores, teniendo que convertirlos en tipos de datos que no son realmente. Y, no digamos nada si tienes que hacer cálculos.
